# Sliding menu on both sides with two separate lists

Tags: android, listview, slider, slidetoggle, swipe-gesture

I am working in an app which has sliding menu on both sides. I tried using navigation drawer but was not able to bring the menu by pushing the main screen to right side as in facebook. So I used Slidingmenu library as in https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/. That is working nicely But the Problem I am facing is that same list is on both sides. Plz help me how to bring separate lists for left menu and right menu.

Here is my code

```
sm = getSlidingMenu();
sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
sm.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleListFragment())
.commit();
```

In SampleListFragment class is have created dynamic list for left menu and in SampleListRight class for right menu. I could'nt bring SampleListRight  class in my code.
Plz help me......

Comment: did you use `Fragment` class?

Comment: Yes @Shayan pourvatan.

Comment: so handle that on there or call different fragment for your menu

Comment: you are achieve this also with android default drawerlayout without using library..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your code by this:

```
getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_right);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menuRight, new MenuRightFragment()).commit();

getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_left);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menuLeft, new MenuLeftFragment()).commit();
```

create two separate lists in MenuRightFragment() and MenuLeftFragment() class.

Answer (score 0):

1. MenuFragment is left fragment
2. RightFragment is right fragment
3. Make a list in both fragment  like as you want

   ```
       sm = getSlidingMenu();
   // set slidder mode
   sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);

   sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
   sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
   sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
   sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
   sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
   //set right slider mode
   sm.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.right_main);

   // Setting the Behind Left View
   setBehindContentView(R.layout.left_main);
   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction();
       leftFragment = new MenuFragment();

       t.replace(R.id.left_container, leftFragment, MenuFragment.TAG);
       t.commit();
   } else {
       leftFragment = (ListFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
               .findFragmentByTag(MenuFragment.TAG);
   }
   // Setting the Behind right View
   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction();
       rightFragment = new RightFragment();

       t.replace(R.id.right_container, rightFragment, RightFragment.TAG);
       t.commit();
   } else {
       rightFragment = (ListFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
               .findFragmentByTag(RightFragment.TAG);
   }
   ```

Comment: menu is not opening when swiping from centre of the screen only working when swiping from margin

Comment: Hey Dude just change it sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.LEFT); to sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT)

Answer (score 0):

use this layout for both left and right side drawer and in framelayout replace your fragment whichever you want...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_right"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```